# No funciona mi apk en android 4.4.4

Tags: android, react-native

Cree una apk con **React-Native** para que se visualice en una **tablet con android 4.4.4** utilizando el comando `expo build:android -t apk`, pero esta me dice `Error de análisis: Se ha producido un problema al analizar el paquete.` al intentar instalarla en el dispositivo físico.

La Apk es solo una aplicación inicial que cree con el comando `expo init prueba`.
Este es mi archivo `Android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Este es mi `AndroidManifest.xml` en donde hice algunas modificaciones

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.prueba">
    <!-- END OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="19"
      android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

      <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="YOUR-APP-URL-HERE" />
      <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="YOUR-APP-SDK-VERSION-HERE" />

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

En el, quité algunos permisos que podían estar impidiendo que funcionara en el dispositivo pero no cambió en nada el resultado final.
Necesito lograr que se vea **exclusivamente para este dispositivo** para poder empezar a construir. Alguna ayuda? por favor

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema relacionado con el error:

```
Error de análisis: Se ha producido un problema al analizar el paquete.
```

o

```
Parse Error: There was a problem parsing the package.
```

**Se debe principalmente a que la aplicaciòn no es compatible con el sistema operativo o con el hardware.**

Comentas que no esta funcionando en una tablet con android 4.4.4, este error he visto sucede principalmente cuando el minSdkVersion definido para tu aplicaciòn ya no soporta tu dispositivo.

De acuerdo a tu archivo `build.gradle` tienes definido `minSdkVersion = 19` lo cual indica que soporta hasta Android 4.4 como minimo, pero es importante verifiques si tu dispositivo tiene `KitKat` o en realidad use alguna versiòn `Jelly Bean`:

```
KitKat  4.4 - 4.4.4 API level 19
Jelly Bean  4.3.x   API level 18
Jelly Bean  4.2.x   API level 17
Jelly Bean  4.1.x   API level 16
```

**Otro causa del problema es que puedes tener definido en tu aplicaciòn el uso de hardware el cual tu dispositivo no lo soporta**.

Por ejemplo si tu aplicaciòn hiciera uso del Giroscopio y tu dispositivo no contara con esta caracteristica, esto podrìa provocar el problema que comentas.

En este caso si el requerimiento de este hardware no es esencial para el funcionamiento de tu aplicaciòn se podrìa definir dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml` como `android:required=false` para que permita la instalaciòn de la aplicaciòn en dispositivos que no tienen esta caracteristica:

```
<uses-feature
  android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope"
  android:required="false"
  ...
  ...
  ...
  />
```

Comment: ♦ gracias por responder. Hice los cambios sugeridos pero no me funcionaron. Será algo más dentro del `Android.Manifest.xml`?